# Open OLEdb connection with Admnistrator privileges

Tags: vb.net, oledb, admin

I made a console (`vb.NET`) for the workers of my company and, one of the things I would like to implement on it, is the visibility of some information available on a `OLEdb` placed on a restricted machine server.

The problem is I can access that server (and read the `OLEdb`) because I'm have `Admnistrator` privileges on that machine server, but the other users can't.

Here's my code:

First I import the `OLEdb` library:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Then I declare the connection variable:

```
Public CON As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\ServerName\Folder\File.accdb")
```

And finally, I try to open the connection:

```
Try
    CON.Open()
Catch
End Try
```

This code works perfectly on my machine, but it doesn't on the others. Is there a way to send the `Administrator` credentials through this piece of code in order to read the `OLEdb` successfully on the other machines without giving them `Admnistrator` privileges on the server?

A few notes: First, I'm not asking to "hack" the system! I have the credentials to access the database! Second, if anyone wants, I will post the catched exception, but I know it's an `Admnistrator` privileges problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If the remote resource needs credentials, you can use [WNetAddConnection2W](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2w) to create a connection and redirect it to a local device (something like `net use ...`). A [sample usage](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.WNetAddConnection2) on PInvoke.net.

Comment: Thanks... Since nobody said anything, I did some profound research and found that exact approach! I think I'm almost done!